# Pandas: reindex with custom function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to reindex data with custom a function. My data looks as follows:

```
                        AAA    BBB    CCC    DDD
Time                                             
2009-01-30 09:30:00  6407.04  43.90  44.01  85.11
2009-01-30 09:39:00  6403.20  43.82  44.01  84.93
2009-01-30 09:40:00  6400.00  43.90  44.03  84.90
2009-01-30 09:45:00  6396.16  43.97  44.04  84.91
2009-01-30 09:48:00  6393.60  44.02  44.07  84.81
2009-01-30 09:55:00  6400.00  44.31  44.14  84.78
2009-01-30 09:56:00  6406.40  44.36  44.16  84.57
2009-01-30 09:59:00  6426.24  44.36  44.11  84.25
2009-01-30 10:00:00  6438.40  44.32  44.09  84.32
2009-01-30 10:06:00  6495.36  44.43  44.16  84.23
```

Its a minute data of some stocks prices. I would like to split the trading day into 5 parts and resample my data.
I start with creating custom index:

```
index_date = pd.date_range('2009-01-30', '2016-03-01')
    index_date = pd.Series(index_date)
    index_time = pd.date_range('09:30:00', '16:00:00', freq='78min')
    index_time = pd.Series(index_time.time)

    index = index_date.apply(
        lambda d: index_time.apply(
            lambda t: datetime.combine(d, t)
            )
        ).unstack().sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Lets assume that I want to apply basic percent change function:

```
def percent_change(x):
    if len(x):
        return (x[-1]-x[0])/x[0]
```

The desired dataset sholud look as follows:

```
                      AAA    BBB  CCC  DDD

2009-01-30 09:30:00    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-01-30 10:48:00     y     y    y    y    # where y is the output of the    
2009-01-30 12:06:00     x     x    x    x      percent_change function from
2009-01-30 13:24:00                            9:30 to 14:48
2009-01-30 14:42:00                          # x is the output of the
2009-01-30 16:00:00                            percent_change function 
2009-01-31 09:30:00                            from 10:49 to 12:06, etc
2009-01-31 10:48:00
```

A larger sample of my data can be found here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h29xlpveb1o7p2u/data.csv?dl=0
How could I do that?

Comment: can you post a desired data set (including a new index)?

Comment: Added to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [182]: %paste
(df.groupby(df.index.date)
   .apply(lambda x: x.resample('78T',
                               loffset=pd.Timedelta('24minute')).mean())
   .ffill()
   .pct_change()
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[182]:
                                    vxxc
           Time
2009-02-02 2009-02-02 09:30:00       NaN
           2009-02-02 10:48:00 -0.010745
           2009-02-02 12:06:00 -0.006372
           2009-02-02 13:24:00 -0.003701
           2009-02-02 14:42:00  0.001614
           2009-02-02 16:00:00 -0.005668
2009-02-03 2009-02-03 09:30:00 -0.009334
           2009-02-03 10:48:00 -0.007039
           2009-02-03 12:06:00 -0.002014
           2009-02-03 13:24:00 -0.002705
           2009-02-03 14:42:00 -0.017530
           2009-02-03 16:00:00 -0.004704
           2009-02-03 17:18:00 -0.001893
2009-02-04 2009-02-04 09:30:00 -0.019076
           2009-02-04 10:48:00 -0.002563
           2009-02-04 12:06:00  0.002348
           2009-02-04 13:24:00  0.010099
           2009-02-04 14:42:00  0.013081
           2009-02-04 16:00:00 -0.000264
           2009-02-04 17:18:00  0.007121
2009-02-05 2009-02-05 09:30:00  0.026527
           2009-02-05 10:48:00 -0.013580
           2009-02-05 12:06:00 -0.018056
           2009-02-05 13:24:00 -0.005020
           2009-02-05 14:42:00 -0.006316
           2009-02-05 16:00:00  0.003269
2009-02-06 2009-02-06 09:30:00 -0.030773
           2009-02-06 10:48:00  0.001088
           2009-02-06 12:06:00  0.010469
           2009-02-06 13:24:00 -0.008337
...                                  ...
2009-02-23 2009-02-23 09:30:00  0.002312
           2009-02-23 10:48:00  0.012162
           2009-02-23 12:06:00  0.009785
           2009-02-23 13:24:00  0.008687
           2009-02-23 14:42:00  0.000421
           2009-02-23 16:00:00  0.012550
2009-02-24 2009-02-24 09:30:00 -0.009290
           2009-02-24 10:48:00 -0.017526
           2009-02-24 12:06:00 -0.004194
           2009-02-24 13:24:00 -0.021528
           2009-02-24 14:42:00 -0.027898
           2009-02-24 16:00:00 -0.012646
2009-02-25 2009-02-25 09:30:00  0.021827
           2009-02-25 10:48:00  0.001863
           2009-02-25 12:06:00 -0.012693
           2009-02-25 13:24:00 -0.006884
           2009-02-25 14:42:00 -0.013019
           2009-02-25 16:00:00 -0.008020
2009-02-26 2009-02-26 09:30:00 -0.015104
           2009-02-26 10:48:00 -0.011319
           2009-02-26 12:06:00  0.019160
           2009-02-26 13:24:00  0.016271
           2009-02-26 14:42:00  0.003807
           2009-02-26 16:00:00  0.007333
2009-02-27 2009-02-27 09:30:00  0.023949
           2009-02-27 10:48:00 -0.027659
           2009-02-27 12:06:00 -0.006932
           2009-02-27 13:24:00 -0.003167
           2009-02-27 14:42:00  0.005263
           2009-02-27 16:00:00  0.010594

[118 rows x 1 columns]
```

**OLD answer:**

you can do it this way:

```
In [104]: df.resample('18T').pct_change()
C:\envs\py35\Scripts\ipython:1: FutureWarning: .resample() is now a deferred operation
use .resample(...).mean() instead of .resample(...)
Out[104]:
                          AAA       BBB       CCC       DDD
Time
2009-01-30 09:18:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2009-01-30 09:36:00 -0.001373  0.000626  0.000625 -0.002614
2009-01-30 09:54:00  0.005477  0.009755  0.002146 -0.005389
```

or if we want to get rid of the `FutureWarning`:

```
In [109]: df.resample('18T').mean().pct_change()
Out[109]:
                          AAA       BBB       CCC       DDD
Time
2009-01-30 09:18:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2009-01-30 09:36:00 -0.001373  0.000626  0.000625 -0.002614
2009-01-30 09:54:00  0.005477  0.009755  0.002146 -0.005389
```

**NOTE:** i've used 18 minutes interval instead of `78T`, because your sample data has less than 78 minutes of data, so change `18T` to `78T` for your real data set

Comment: Resample will not work in my case, since you cannot equally divide the day by by 78 minutes (adding custom base parameter will not help as well), so it will shift the index (that's why I created custom index). I want every day to start exactly from 9:30 and end on 16:00.

Comment: @VitaliHalapjan, ok, i see, can you post/upload somewhere a bigger DF containing a data for at least two days?

Comment: Added a dropbox link to the initial question

Comment: @VitaliHalapjan, the latest time in you your sample data (dropbox)  is `10:59` - is it a common rule for your real data?

Comment: There was a mistake in the file I uploaded, there is a new one now (with only one ticker)

Comment: @VitaliHalapjan, see UPDATE in my answer - is that what you want?

Comment: I believe that pct_change() is not calculated properly here. It should be: (value at 10:48 - value at 9:00) / value at 9:00

Comment: df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: x.resample('78T',base=24).apply(percent_change)) does the trick! Thank you!

Comment: as of 0.18.1 you don't need the apply as .resample is a method on .groupby

Comment: @Jeff, thank you for the hint. But the `DataFrameGroupBy.resample()` doesn't accept `base` and `loffset` parameters - it produces `TypeError: _maybe_process_deprecations() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base'` error - do you know why?

Comment: sure it does - but fixed in 0.18.2 (forthcoming soon) - in general don't even show .apply solns they are inefficient and not idiomatic